# Change colors in a livecharts chart with MAUI

Tags: c#, maui, livecharts

In my MAUI application, I added [LiveChart.dev](https://livecharts.dev/) graphs version 2.0.0-RC1. It is working and the code is

```
<lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding Series}" 
                    XAxes="{Binding XAxes}" YAxes="{Binding YAxes}"
                    LegendPosition="{Binding LegendPosition}"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="250" />
```

The result is good.

[image]

Because this is a mobile app, I also enabled the dark mode. When it is dark, I can't see the label on the axeses or in the legend.

Is there a way to change the color of the labels?

Comment: use the `LegendTextPaint` property

Comment: I tried but if I pass an HEX color is not working. What do I have to pass?

Comment: A Paint object I guess.  Read the docs

Comment: @Enrico hex converters are not implemented yet, please bind a paint instance.

Comment: @bto.rdz thank you so much for your answer. Is the paint instance from SkiaSharp?

Comment: One of these: https://livecharts.dev/docs/Maui/2.0.0-rc1/Overview.Paints